# changing user with federated security in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, saml, federated-identity

I have been tasked with implementing user switching in a component that connects to a WCF service using federated security.

I can use Tokenclaims.ReadClaim() to find out what username is currently logged on.

How do I invalidate this token and force another logon?

I have tried changing the username and password on the credentials, but that doesn't seem to do the trick, as the existing claim is still being used.

help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into writing a custom [`ClientCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.aspx) subclass. In this class you can manage what tokens are used and when for each call. You can read more about custom client credentials in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730868.aspx).

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632463/claim-based-authentication-using-wcf ?